# algorithm analysis for upper bound

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

```
>Problem: n^4 + 100n^2 + 50. 

>Solution given: n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= 2n^4 for all n>=1
>                n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 = O(n^4) with c=2 and n0 = 100
```

But when n is 1, the above function will be "4+100+50 <= 2" which is not true. How can i derive the correct upper bound for this problem or let me know if the given solution is wrong.

The problem is from Data structures and algorithms made easy in java.

Comment: Typo? `n >= 11` does it.

Comment: the book says as n>=1.

Comment: the problem is here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~hsinmu/courses/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=dsa_12spring:dsame_chap1.pdf page 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct way to state the solution would be

```
n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= c*n^4 for all n>=n0 with c=2 and n0 = 100

=> n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 = O(n^4)
```

Comment: There is no unique solution, the one I wrote is also correct, cf the "No Uniqueness" section on page 17 of the [script you linked](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~hsinmu/courses/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=dsa_12spring:dsame_chap1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

We need to find, smallest rate of growth, `g(n)` such that

```
c g(n) >= f(n) for n>=k.
```

For some constant value of c and k, the above equation will hold true. We do not consider lower values of n. This means `g(n)` for low values of `n` is not important. For large values of `n`, `g(n)` will be the maximum rate of growth of `f(n)`.

Here, `f(n)= n^4 + 100 n^2 + 50`

When `n` is very large, `g(n) = n^4`

Find `c` and `k`, so that `c n^4 >= n^4 + 100 n ^2 + 50`

If we discard, lower terms `100 n^2` and `50`. we can say `c` should be `2`.

```
2 n^4 >= n^4 .
```

To find value of `k`, try substituting `n^2 = t`, `n^4 = t^2` and `c=2`,

```
2t^2 >= t^2 + 100t + 50

t^2 >= 100t +50
```

If i start putting values of `t` from `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, and `10` and `t^2 =100`

At `10`, i still have

```
100,00 <= 100, 00 +50
```

At `t=11`, and `t^2 = 121`, i have below

```
14,641 >= 12150.
```

So my `k` will be `11`.

Similarly for the other equation, `f(n) = 3n +8`

`g(n)` will be `n`. Find `c` and `k` so that below is `true`.

```
c.g(n) >= f(n)
```

`4n>=3n+`8, discard constant `8` to find `c`, and insert constant `8` back in equation to find `k`.

At `k=8`, we have `32>=32`.